# Calculating Cyclometric Complexity?

Tags: architecture, software-design, cyclomatic-complexity, code-complexity

How do you properly calculate Cyclmetric Complexity?

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) the cyclometric complexity of the following code:

```
if (c1())
    f1();
else
    f2();

if (c2())
    f3();
else
    f4();
```

is 3. But I understand it as 4:

- 2 * 2 = 4
- Looking at the graph (see image) there are 4 distinct paths - 2 (left left, left right, right left, right right).

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference between [cyclometric complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) and full branch coverage.

*Cyclometric complexity* is a pure mathematical metric. Plainly put - measuring the number of paths that add a **new branch** to the current paths set.

So in your example - we start with an empty set. `false/false` is one path (#1), and then `true/false` adds a new branch (the first `if`) (#2). Then `false/true` adds a new branch (the second `if`) (#3).
However **the path `true/true` does not add a new branch to the set**, since all of the points it visits can also be visited by combining path #2 and path #3.

This results remains no matter what is the order that you're adding the paths to the set - always the last (4th) path will not add a new branch that wasn't visited by the previous paths.

*Full branch coverage* - on the other hand - is more of a software metric. Since we know that in software sometimes testing two branches together can give a different result then just relying on testing the first branch, and separately testing the second branch.

In graph theory cyclometric complexity does not take into account those cross-relations between the branches (just the number of "new" branches), but in software engineering if you want full coverage you need to test all of the possible paths.

Generally - number of minimal tests required <= cyclometric complexity <= number of tests for full branch coverage.